# AlarmManager to start an activity with onBootReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I developed an app to start an activity at everyday 11pm. I also added a boot receiver on it. the output of this app gives nothing but a blank screen. Kindly someone help me.

This is my first class OnBootService

```
public class boot extends BroadcastReceiver  {
 @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent bootintent) {
      Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent();
      mServiceIntent.setAction("com.thenga.nilavilak.timer_test001.alarm");
      context.startService(mServiceIntent);
     }
    }
```

This is my alarm class

```
public class alarm extends boot {
    public void onReceiveboot(final Context context) {
    Calendar vtime = Calendar.getInstance();
    vtime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
    vtime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    vtime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    ;

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
    new Intent(context, sasi.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, vtime.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

 }
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my third class the want to run at 11 pm

```
public class sasi extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Output received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I actually dont understand what's the problem. Do you mean your activity doesn't start at given time? If so, are you sure you added your receiver to AndroidManifest.xml?
Or if you have another problem please describe it in detail

Comment: Yes, i added the receiver to the manifest. my problem is, the activity is not running at the alarm time. and thank you for the interest in my question, serejja.

Comment: Post your manifest. Do you know if your `onReceive()` is getting called?